# SQL Case statement returns wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case

I have the following sql statement which is designed to give the field t1.DWPostedDateKey a value if the t2.InventoryStatusCode changes to 'p'.  The starting value of t1.DWPostedDateKey is NULL, and if the t2.InventoryStatusCode doesn't change, I want it stay NULL.

```
select
t1.DateKey,
t1.DWPostedDateKey,
(CASE WHEN t2.InventoryStatusCode = 'p' 
             and (t1.InventoryStatusKey != t2.InventoryStatusKey) THEN 
     CONVERT(int, GetDate(), 112)
ELSE 
     t1.DWPostedDateKey
END)
from table1 t1 inner join
   table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
```

The problem is I don't get NULL ?  Here is an example of the results:

```
DateKey     DWPostedDateKey   (No column name)
20150413    NULL              42106
20150413    NULL              42106
20150413    NULL              42106
20150413    20150414          20150414
20150413    20150414          20150414
20150413    20150414          20150414
```

What is 42106 doing in there?  I want it to remain a NULL value.

Comment: But the case is not checking DWPostedDateKey at all? The result doesn't include InventoryStatusCode or InventoryStatusKey but I would assume those are what the case statement has there...

Comment: I just put the relevant part of the sql statement in the question.  The problem originated in an update statement - but the behaviour showed here is the problem.  I may decide to check the DWPostedDateKey and not change it if a value is there already - but the bottom line remains: if DWPostedDateKey is NULL I want to leave it as NULL

Comment: If you just change it to be "CASE WHEN  DWPostedDateKey is NOT NULL and t2.Inventory ...", will that fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line `CONVERT(int, GetDate(), 112)`, specifically in the `int`.

It is converting the `datetime` to `int` and SQL Server when you do that is returning the number of days since 1/1/1900. (That is the number you see)

This will return what you need
`CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(), 112)`

if you need an integer try with this
`CAST(CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(), 112) AS INTEGER)`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL code works correctly as far as I can test it. It seems to be in your data that you're getting a int value instead of a NULL value.

It would help if you post the rows from table t1 and t2 here that are the base for this resultset.

However, when I reproduce it, I can only get it to produce an int in the third column when you change the value of 'InventoryStatus' in t2.

```
declare @table1 table (
    [key] int,
    DateKey nvarchar(8),
    DWPostedDateKey nvarchar(8),
    InventoryStatusKey int
)

declare @table2 table (
    [key] int,
    InventoryStatusKey int,
    InventoryStatusCode nvarchar(1)
)

insert into @table1 values (1, N'20150413', NULL, 1)
insert into @table1 values (2, N'20150413', NULL, 1)
insert into @table1 values (3, N'20150413', NULL, 1)
insert into @table1 values (4, N'20150413', N'20150414', 1)
insert into @table1 values (6, N'20150413', N'20150414', 1)

insert into @table2 values (1, 1, 'a')
insert into @table2 values (1, 2, 'a')
insert into @table2 values (3, 2, 'p') 
insert into @table2 values (4, 2, 'a')
insert into @table2 values (6, 1, 'a')

select
    t1.DateKey,
    t1.DWPostedDateKey,
    (CASE WHEN 
        t2.InventoryStatusCode = 'p' 
        and (t1.InventoryStatusKey != t2.InventoryStatusKey) 
     THEN 
        CONVERT(int, GetDate(), 112)
ELSE 
     t1.DWPostedDateKey
END)
from @table1 t1 inner join
   @table2 t2 on t1.[key] = t2.[key]
```

I change the value of the InventoryStatusCode from 'a' to 'p' and the result it what you're getting.